# Is it possible to sniff out what font a browser is currently using from server side?

Tags: html, wordpress, browser, web

Basically I want to echo back to the user what font they are using. Is it possible to do? If there is a Wordpress plugin for it, that would be extra nice.

The page in question is going to show Chinese characters. My friend wants to have one column with a character as it looks in mainland China, and then a column with how it looks in Taiwan (there are slight, but distinct, differences - see the article at the link), both these columns will be pictures. And then a third column that displays the character using your font. It would be neat if there was a way to know which variant the user's font is displaying. But now that I write it out, it seems like a very hard problem.

[Hacking Chinese on character differences](http://www.hackingchinese.com/chinese-character-variants-and-fonts-for-language-learners/)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking? If you left the font to default, the page would display the name of the font your browser ends up using.

Comment: A browser uses the font that a website tells it to use (if it's available) and uses the default font (which can change between browsers) if the website hasn't specified a font, or the font is not available. You can also use multiple fonts on a website, would you want to inform the user of all of the fonts on a particular page? I think you need to expand your question.

Comment: Do you *really* want to do this server side? Because I think that's likely to be impossible. It may be doable client-side, given that things like the [WhatFont](http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html) bookmarklet seem to identify the font that's actually being used from JavaScript...